ELK + winston not sending logs to index
I have this logger in my nodejs app  whcih correctly logs to the console ...
import winston, { format, LeveledLogMethod, Logger } from 'winston';
import { ElasticsearchTransport } from 'winston-elasticsearch';

const esTransportOpts = {
  level: 'info',
  indexSuffixPattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  clientOpts: {
    node: 'https://<public-dns-host>:9200',
    maxRetries: 5,
    requestTimeout: 10000,
    sniffOnStart: false,
    auth: {
      username: 'elastic',
      password: '*******',
    },
    log: 'trace', // Enable detailed logging
  },
  indexPrefix: 'svcbeat',
  flushInterval: 2000, // Flush logs every 2 seconds
};

const esTransport = new ElasticsearchTransport(esTransportOpts);
esTransport.on('error', err => {
  console.error('Elasticsearch transport error:', err);
});

// ES payload debug
if (typeof esTransport.log === 'function') {
  const originalLog = esTransport.log.bind(esTransport);
  esTransport.log = (info, callback) => {
    console.log('Payload to Elasticsearch:', info);
    return originalLog(info, callback);
  };
} else {
  console.error('Elasticsearch transport does not have a log method.');
}

export const logger: Logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    winston.format.json({
      replacer: (key: string, value: any) => {
        if (key === 'trace_id' || key === 'span_id' || key === 'trace_flags') return undefined;
        if (key === 'level') return value?.toUpperCase();
        if (key === 'message' && value === '') return undefined;

        return value;
      },
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    esTransport, // Log to Elasticsearch
  ],
  handleExceptions: true,
});

logger.info('Testing Elasticsearch logging', { action: 'testElasticsearchLog', timeStamp: Date.now() });

this is the payload debug
{"action":"testElasticsearchLog","level":"INFO","message":"Testing Elasticsearch logging","timeStamp":1733389347517}
Payload to Elasticsearch: {
  action: 'testElasticsearchLog',
  timeStamp: 1733389347517,
  level: 'info',
  message: 'Testing Elasticsearch logging',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'info',
  [Symbol(splat)]: [ { action: 'testElasticsearchLog', timeStamp: 1733389347517 } ],
  [Symbol(message)]: '{"action":"testElasticsearchLog","level":"INFO","message":"Testing Elasticsearch logging","timeStamp":1733389347517}'
}

however, I don't see any logs in ELK ... why?
The credentials and node url are correct - when I try to manually create a document in that index, it works fine (from the ELK machine but even from remote [my local laptop] machine)
 curl -k -u elastic -X POST "https://<public-dns-host>:9200/svcbeat/_doc" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "message": "This is a test log entry from elkloguser",
      "level": "info",
      "timestamp": "2024-12-05T12:00:00Z",
      "action": "testLog"
    }'

any idea what am I missing?
